# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 24: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, oracle, encoding, sqlalchemy, character-encoding

I'm assuming the database is encoded at UTF-8 but I'm trying to decode it as CP1252, the only thing is that I'm including UTF-8 as my encoding so I'm not sure why I'm still getting the error. Data set includes European Information (so the different countries). The NLS language is English and the Character set is WE8MSWIN1252. I've looked at the similar questions answers however none of the solutions work.

```
engine = sa.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@host:port/dbname", encoding='utf-8')
```

which then returns the error above of

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
>   24: character maps to